# How to avoid nodes to be quarantined in Akka Cluster?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

The doc of [Akka Remoting (Artery)](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting-artery.html#quarantine) describes quarantine as follows:
[image]
Nodes will be quarantined when remote failure detector triggers in Akka Remote, but will not in Akka Cluster.

The doc of [Akka Cluster](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-usage.html#failure-detector) describes quarantine as follows:
[image]
Nodes will be quarantined when there are too many unacknowledged system messages, but will not be quarantined when failure detector triggers.

So I have 3 questions:

1. In Akka Cluster, failure detector triggers don’t cause nodes to be
   quarantined, so what are their roles?
2. “too many unacknowledged system messages”, what’s the number of “too many” ? Can we addjust it ?
3. How to config in Akka Cluster to make nodes will not or be harder to be quarantined ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resovled [here](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/how-to-avoid-nodes-to-be-quarantined-in-akka-cluster/1932) by [Patrik Nordwall](https://discuss.lightbend.com/u/patriknw/summary).